# Limit dynamic IP port range

Tags: c#, windows, sockets

I have created a server application that dynamically opens ports for its clients. I now use a socket that binds to port 0, so I get a random assigned port. This works fine, but the disadvantage is that I need to open all ports in the firewall for this process.

I would rather restrict the range between i.e. 40000-41000 and pick random ports in this range. Is there a method to let the OS pick a free port in this range?

Of cource, I could pick a port myself in this range and if it's free, then use it. Otherwise try another port, until we have found a free port. I don't think it's a great solution. I could register my own ports, but other services could also reserve ports in this range.

Anyone a solution? I work on a Windows Server 2008 R2 system with a custom C# 4.5 server.

Comment: How do you expect the client to guess at the correct port number?

Comment: I have a command that sets up the port forwarding and it responds with the hostname and portnumber (it already works that way). The requester can then connect to the endpoint to do whatever it wants to do. No guessing required :-)

Comment: If you are using Windows Firewall, it can be configured to allow access based on the application rather than the port number.  That would seem a simpler solution here.

Comment: That's whay I have done right now, but in the production environment we need to forward ports in another firewall. I just don't want to forward everything (that would defeat the use of the firewall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IPGlobalProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can gives you the current busy ports. Here is a way you can do it :

```
// Returns available port number or zero if no port is available
public static int GetFirstAvailableRandomPort (int startPort, int stopPort) 
{
     Random r = new Random() ; 

     IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
     TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

    var busyPorts = tcpConnInfoArray.Select(t => t.LocalEndPoint.Port).Where(v => v >= startPort&& v <= stopPort ).ToArray() ; 

    var firstAvailableRandomPort = Enumerable.Range(startPort, stopPort - startPort).OrderBy(v => r.Next()).FirstOrDefault(p => !busyPorts .Contains(p))

    return firstAvailableRandomPort ; 
}
```

**Usage** :

```
var randomPort  = GetFirstAvailableRandomPort(40000, 41000) ;
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that class, but it will do the job. I will need some locking, because multiple threads might request a port simultaneously.

Comment: This would seem to have a race condition with other processes/software if your port range overlaps with the dynamic/ephemeral port range used by the operating system. You could select port number, and it could be in-use by the time you do the bind.